# ¿Hay alguna forma igualar estos valores de JQuery en C# MVC?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

tengo una vista en MVC la cual al dar click sobre un boton me debe regresar a una vista anterior obteniendo los valores de metodo, controlador y formulario al que me redireccionara, ya obtengo los valores pero no se como asignarlos en el @Url.Action().

```
    // CODIGO DEL CONTROLADOR
    [HttpPost]
    [ActionName("CALP")]
    [DataAccessService("SQL-FYL", "SP_FYL_H_VoBoAprobador")]
    public ActionResult UpdateVoBoCALP(string comentario, int StageID, int ? StageRet)
    {
        Result result = new Result();

        try
        {
            object[] parametros = new object[] { "U", Session["IDHallazgo"], StageID, 1, 1, Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")), "C.ERIVPE", Session["ID_Sistema"], comentario };
            DataAccessHelper.ExecuteNonQuery("SQL-FYL", "SP_FYL_H_VoBoAprobador", parametros);

            result.Message = "Hallazgo " + Session["IdHallazgo"] + " Actualizado";

            result.isSuccess = true;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            result.isSuccess = false;
        }

        return this.Json(result); //RETORNO COMO JSON
    }
    //CODIGO EN LA VISTA
    $("#BtnRechazar").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: '@Url.Action("CALP", "FlujoAprobacion")',
            data: {
                comentario: $("#_txtComentario").val(),
                StageID: $("#_cmbEtapa").val()
            }
        }).done(function (result) {
            var cntrl = result.contr; var met = result.met; var frm = result.frm;
            SolicitudExitosaRechazo(cntrl, met, frm);
        }).fail(function () {
            alert("Error Al Rechazar La Etapa ");
        });
    });

    //FUNCION
    function SolicitudExitosaRechazo(cntrl, met, frm) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url:  '@Url.Action(met, cntrl)', //EN ESTA PARTE TENGO EL CONFLICTO @Url.Action ES CODIGO C# Y NO SE COMO ASIGNAR ESTOS VALORES (met, cntrl) QUE ESTAN COMO JQUERY
            data: $('#' + frm).serialize()
        }).done(function (result) {
            $('#mainContent').html(result);
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes en primer lugar seguir haciendo la referencia  de la **@Url.Action** como en la primera función como en la imagen, antes de hacer la petición ajax declaras la variable params que tendra todas las variables que mandaras y la mandas serializada (esto en el caso que solo mandes parametros  y/ o models).

```
//Vista
function SolicitudExitosaRechazo(cntrl, met, frm) {
    // declaras una variable params que tendra todas los parametros que enviaras
    var params = {
        cntrl:cntrl,
        met: met, 
        frm: frm
    };
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        contentType: "application/json", // le dices que enviaras el contenido de la peticion en json
        url: '@Url.Action("MyAction", "MyController")', 
        data: JSON.stringify(params), //serializas la variable params
    }).done(function (result) {
        $('#mainContent').html(result);
    });
}
```

Si lo que quieres es mandar un Form (frm.serialize()) y ademas otros parámetros entonces tendrás que hacerlo de la siguiente forma:

```
// en el la VISTA
function SolicitudExitosaRechazo(cntrl, met, frm) {

    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: '@Url.Action("MyAction", "MyController")', 
        data: $('#' + frm).serialize() + "&cntrl=" + cntrl+ "&met=" + met ,
    }).done(function (result) {
        $('#mainContent').html(result);
    });
}


//En tu controller
       [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult MyAction( FormCollection frm,  string cntrl, string met)
    {
        // mi actionresult
    }
```

Comment: Gracias, ya lo pude resolver.

Comment: Lo que estaba buscando era en mi result asignar una url para porteriormente seguirla, estaba un poco confundido:

return this.Json(result); 

Antes de hacer el return, le asigne la url de la siguiente manera:

resul.Url = Url.Action(list[0].MetodoActual, list[0].ControllerActual);
result.Urla = list[0].FrmActual;

function SolicitudExitosaRechazo(result) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url:  result.Url, 
            data: $('#' + resul.Urla).serialize()
        }).done(function (result) {
            $('#mainContent').html(result);
        });

Comment: Ya veo, que bueno que te haya servido